# I want to Check BLE Advertising in Killed State Using Core Bluetooth Is It Possible In IOS In Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to Check BLE Advertising in Killed State Using Core Bluetooth Is It Possible In IOS In Swift ?

I Want To Check With Two IOS Devices Is It Possible Or Not ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know it is possible to check bluetooth is advertising in killed state or not